# All possibilities of bands compositions in a single processing

Tags: arcgis-pro

Instead of combining the bands, I want to do all possible band combinations at once via a raster calculator or other tool.

Knowing this: 8 bands in all possible combinations. That's C(8, 3) = 8! / (3! * (8-3)!) = 56. or P(8, 3) = 8! / (8-3)! = 336 compositions if we consider the possibilities of different orders, in the 3 bands to be combined.

Ignoring the spectral behavior of each band. The objective is to make only combinations with the available bands.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the documentation for itertools.

To get the 56 bands use combinations from itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations
 
# Get all combinations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and length 3
comb = combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] , 3)
 
# Print the obtained combinations
for i, bands in enumerate(list(comb)):
    print(f"{i}\t{bands}")
```

To get the 336 permutations

```
from itertools import permutations
 
# Get all permutations 
perm = permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3)
 
# Print the obtained permutations
for i, bands in enumerate(list(perm)):
    print(f"{i}\t{bands}")
```